# How do you know if stone-ground flour is truly milled with stones?

Tags: flour, wheat, milling

I ran across [this article](http://www.measuresofsuccess.com/News+and+Press+Releases/Latest+News/663.aspx) that originally appeared in USA Today in 2006. The author makes the claim that the label is unregulated and that manufacturers can simply say "100% stone ground" even if it's processed by a roller mill.

Does anyone know if, 6 years later, this is still true? If so, does anyone know which brands truly are stone ground?

Comment: In most western countries you can't just say what you like on any label. A quick test; spread a sample on matt black paper, and observe it under bright sunlight. You will see the occasional glint of "stone" dust

Comment: @TFD : you might not be able to say *whatever* you like, but there's always ways of stretching the truth ... give all of the flour a pass through a stone, then finish under metal ... and is it "100% stone ground"?  I'd say it's not, but you can be assured there are lawyers who will take up the other side of it.  (it's like the 'all natural' corn syrup ... corn is 100% natural, corn syrup comes from corn, ergo, all natural corn syrup)

Comment: You could use stone rollers, for that matter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FDA does not currently have a legal definition of stone ground.

Companies like Hodgson's Mill, Bob's Red Mill, and Arrowhead Mills have petitioned the FDA to set a definition in the past under the concept of truth in labeling, to no avail.

[Petition example](http://www.fda.gov/ohrms/dockets/dailys/03/Feb03/022003/01p-0290-cp00002-vol-1.pdf?utm_campaign=Google2&utm_source=fdaSearch&utm_medium=website&utm_term=stone%20ground&utm_content=4)

Answer (score -2):

True stone ground would be hard to find. It will contain stone dust. Very hard on the teeth. But as said put on black paper under a strong light to see the dust. It would be a high priced flour if found. As stone grinding is slow to do. But does not produce the heat modern milling does. So a few nor nutrients in the flour.